# Initializing a final field in an enum, where the value is loaded through a method which throws an Exception?

Tags: java, enums, initialization, instance-variables

So I'm trying to load an `Image` as part of the constants in an inner enum.  Something like the following:

```
public enum State {
    HAPPY, SAD; 

    private final Image image;
}
```

Currently, I have it loading from an external constant and a static initializer like so:

```
private static final Image HAPPY_IMAGE;
static {
    Image happyImage = null;
    try {
        happyImage = ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/file.gif"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.fatal("Failed to load image.");
    }
    HAPPY_IMAGE = happyImage;
}

public enum State {
    HAPPY (HAPPY_IMAGE);

    private final Image image;

    private State(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

I don't want to use this approach, though, for two reasons.  First, it's a bit more verbose than seems necessary.  But more importantly, it creates a redundant constant.  There's no reason to have `HAPPY_IMAGE` when the image should be accessed via `State.HAPPY.getImage()`.

The following is valid, but I can't assign a different value for each enum value.

```
public enum State {
    HAPPY;

    private final Image image;
    {
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("path/to/file.gif"));
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            LOGGER.fatal("Failed to load image.");
        }
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

So is there any way I can accomplish this loading of the enum's `final` value?

Comment: Why do you want dynamic loading? The image won't change during runtime, right?

Comment: @fge Right.  I don't want the loading to be dynamic.  I just want to be able to load it directly into the enum without using the constants.  Bad terminology on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An enum can have a constructor.
So you can do the loading there.

```
public enum State {
  HAPPY("path/image.gif");

  private final Image image;     

  private State(String path)
  {
      this.image = ...
  }

  public Image getImage()
  {
      return image;
  }
}
```

Comment: You were quicker, +1 (you might want to move the enum value above the image field)

Comment: Jesus.  Duh.  I'm an idiot.  Talk about overthinking the problem.